# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object (MySQL/Sessions)

Tags: php

I'm aware that this is a common question on here, but I've been through a whole lot of other answers, and cannot understand why this is still failing. So, my apologies, but hopefully someone can point out where this is going wrong!

In **index.php**, the following code is executed:

```
// Set Database Configuration
$dbconfig = array( 
    'host' => getenv('MYSQL_DB_HOST'),
    'user' => getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME'), 
    'pass' => getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'), 
    'name' => getenv('MYSQL_DB_NAME') 
); 

// Start database sessions
$db = oadb::getInstance();
$db->show_errors();
echo $db->prepare("hello");

// Open a new session
$sess = new oasession();
session_start();
```

The **getInstance();** and **$db->prepare()** happen without a problem, and the "hello" text is echoed to confirm this.

When the **new oasession()** is called is where the wheels start to fall off. The **oasessions()** function is a session handler that takes over PHPs normal session handling, and puts it in a MySQL database.

The **sessions.inc.php** includes a class as follows (I've removed some irrelevant functions):

```
class oasession {

   var $life_time;

   function oasession() {

      // Read the maxlifetime setting from PHP
      $this->life_time = get_cfg_var("session.gc_maxlifetime");

      // Register this object as the session handler
      session_set_save_handler( 
        array( &$this, "open" ), 
        array( &$this, "close" ),
        array( &$this, "read" ),
        array( &$this, "write"),
        array( &$this, "destroy"),
        array( &$this, "gc" )
      );

   }

   function open( $save_path, $session_name ) {
        global $sess_save_path;
        $sess_save_path = $save_path;
        // Don't need to do anything. Just return TRUE.
        return true;
   }

   function read( $id ) {
       global $db;

           // Set empty result
           $data = '';

           // Fetch session data from the selected database

           $time = time();

           $newid = $db->prepare($id);
           $sql = "SELECT `session_data` FROM `OA-Auth_sessions` WHERE `session_id` = '$newid' AND `expires` > $time";

           $rs = $db->query($sql);                           
           $a = $db->num_rows($rs);

           if($a > 0) {
             $row = $db->fetch_array($rs);
             $data = $row['session_data'];
           }
           return $data;
        }

    function write( $id, $data ) {
        global $db;

         // Build query                
         $time = time() + $this->life_time;

         $newid = $db->prepare($id);
         $newdata = $db->prepare($data);

         $sql = "REPLACE `OA-Auth_sessions` (`session_id`,`session_data`,`expires`) VALUES('$newid', '$newdata', $time)";

         $rs = $db->query($sql);

         return TRUE;

      }
}
```

It is able to use the read($id) function without any problems, but when it tries to use the write($id, $data) function, it fails with the following error...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in sessions.class.php on line 66
```

...suggesting that the prepare function, executed from $db->prepare() is not a valid object.

I've tried testing this by placing print_r()'s before and after the new oasession(), and both have printed with object descriptions, and there are no problems running other $db->prepare() calls before or after the new oasession() call.

Any thoughts on what may be causing this one?

Thanks very much!

Comment: `hello` is not a valid MySQL statement.

Comment: @Gumbo Correct, but irrelevant. The $db->prepare() function just performs a few things like stripslashes() etc - you can technically pass anything to it, as it is not built to process an entire SQL query. Thanks, though.

Comment: And which one is line 66 ? Are you sure you really assigned `$db` in global context? (Your config snippet might run in a function e.g.) Test with `var_dump($db);` before anything. Also why is that method called `->prepare()` if it's just an escaping function? (Tip: real prepared statements are significantly less effort).

Comment: Beware! Global state is evil! Do not use Singletons for database connections, and don't use `global` to get variables!

Comment: Usually, `prepare` results in a [`PREPARE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/prepare.html).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve this one, as per php.net:

> When using objects as session save handlers, it is important to
>   register the shutdown function with PHP to avoid unexpected
>   side-effects from the way PHP internally destroys objects on shutdown
>   and may prevent the write and close from being called. Typically you
>   should register 'session_write_close' using the
>   register_shutdown_function() function.

Adding the following to the sessions.class.php oasession() function...

```
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
```

...fixed it all up :)